# Better ruby markdown interpreter?

Tags: ruby, markdown

I'm trying to find a markdown interpreter class/module that I can use in a rakefile.

So far I've found [maruku](http://maruku.rubyforge.org/), but I'm a bit wary of beta releases.

Has anyone had any issues with maruku? Or, do you know of a better alternative?

Answer (score 314, accepted):

I use Maruku to process 100,000 - 200,000 documents per day. Mostly forum posts but I also use it on large documents like wiki pages. Maruku is much faster than BlueCloth and it doesn't choke on large documents. It's all Ruby and although the code isn't especially easy to extend and augment, it is doable. We have a few tweaks and extras in our dialect of Markdown.

If you want something that is **pure Ruby**, I definitely recommend Maruku.

For the **fastest option** out there, you probably want RDiscount. The guts are implemented in C.

See also: "[Moving Past BlueCloth](http://tomayko.com/writings/ruby-markdown-libraries-real-cheap-for-you-two-for-price-of-one)" on Ryan Tomayko's blog. 
Ryan's post includes the following benchmark of 100 iterations of a markdown test:

```
BlueCloth: 13.029987s total time, 00.130300s average
   Maruku: 08.424132s total time, 00.084241s average
RDiscount: 00.082019s total time, 00.000820s average
```

#### Update August 2009

BlueCloth2 was released (http://www.deveiate.org/projects/BlueCloth)
It's speed is on par with RDiscount because it is based on RDiscount - it is not pure Ruby.

(Thanks [Jim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/63828/jim-soho))

#### Update November 2009

[Kramdown 1.0 was just released](http://kramdown.rubyforge.org/). I haven't tried it yet, but it is a pure-Ruby Markdown parser that claims to be 5x faster than Maruku.

#### Update April 2011

Maruku hasn't seen a commit since June 2010. You may want to look into Kramdown instead.

A new fast option that is not pure Ruby: GitHub has released Redcarpet, which is based on libupskirt: https://github.com/blog/832-rolling-out-the-redcarpet

#### Update August 2013

Kramdown is still a very healthy project (based on recent commits, outstanding issues, pull requests) and a great choice for a pure Ruby Markdown engine  https://github.com/gettalong/kramdown

Redcarpet is probably still the most commonly used and actively maintained option for people that don't need or want pure Ruby.

Comment: gave you +1 because you put in the Update section!

Comment: I can't begin to say how useful the Update section here is. Just Googling for a Ruby solution leads to a bunch of implementations that were probably great in their day, but this gives a lot of context.

Comment: This is why I love StackOverflow's community (the whole of Exchange, really) - a completely needless and unsolicited generosity and conscientiousness.

Comment: [Kramdown's tests page](http://kramdown.rubyforge.org/tests.html) currently features February 2012 benchmarks of all the libraries.

Comment: I must point out that Kramdown drifts a bit from the Markdown standard; for example, (as I found out) you can't have a link inside a header. You should be wary of that if you happen to have lots of preexisting Markdown documents.

Comment: [RedCarpet](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet) is propably faster than RDiscount && BlueCloth.

Answer (score 8):

The listing at http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/markup_processors.html would be a good place to start looking.

Comment: +1 All these other answers will get outdated pretty fast, but that listing should stay up to date as long as ruby-toolbox is around.

Answer (score 6):

[RDiscount](https://github.com/rtomayko/rdiscount) is Fast and simple to use.

Answer (score 5):

Try [RDiscount](http://github.com/rtomayko/rdiscount/tree/master). BlueCloth is slow and buggy.

Comment: It isn't anymore. It now uses the C discount library.
http://www.deveiate.org/projects/BlueCloth

Answer (score 5):

The benchmark in the answer given by casey use BlueCloth 1. BlueCloth 2 is the fastest these days : http://www.deveiate.org/projects/BlueCloth

Answer (score 1):

I believe [BlueCloth](http://www.deveiate.org/projects/BlueCloth/) is the most prominent one.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a lot of these answers are outdated.

Best thing I've found out there as of now (summer 2013) is the Redcarpet gem: https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet

Answer (score 0):

To ensure you're getting BlueCloth 2, install like this:

```
gem install bluecloth
```

Note that "bluecloth" should be in all lowercase, not camel case.

Source: http://rubygems.org/gems/bluecloth

Answer (score 0):

If you need a fair example for how to use something like Kramdown in a rakefile there is a repo on github with code and articles in markdown.md that can be converted to html with Ruby code syntax highlighting but alas line numbers as well.(I would prefer to turn off line numbering)

If anyone knows how to shut off the line numbering default please tell us.

Anyway the link is https://github.com/elm-city-craftworks/practicing-ruby-manuscripts