# Simple Rails text field formatting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, formatting, textarea

How can I easily allow blog posts (in a Rails app) to be formatted? Minimally I'd like to retain the carriage returns when `text` is displayed as HTML. I guess ideally it'd allow for bold, italic & indentation.

I'm aware of [CKEditor](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor). I just fear it may be overkill, and difficult to implement quickly & easily...

Comment: maintaining line breaks is easy as pie. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format. For bold, italiac etc., ckeditor or tinymce are fine, but I would look into markdown and likes, which have ruby libraries like redcloth, bluecloth etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use Markdown? There are lots of implementations. Refer to this SO post — [Better ruby markdown interpreter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373002/better-ruby-markdown-interpreter)

Comment: Agreed with Markdown. RedCarpet 2 is some pretty sweet tech.

Comment: RedCloth, RedCarpet, BlueCloth... which is preferred/most active/populer and/or easiest to deal with?

Comment: Although I never used it myself, the (apparently) latest and greatest comes from GitHub's RedCarpet. Last link on the SO post I linked in the answer.

Comment: I went with RedCarpet. It was a cinch to install & get working.

Answer (score 5):

wrapping your text by `simple_format(@post.description)` will show line feeds in your text. For additional formatting, you will need to use gem RedCloth or likes.

Comment: wasn't aware of `simple_format`. this is great and solving my "pinch" problem (+1). though leaving question open as I'm still curious what all my options are. thx! pretty good for a "rookie".

Comment: Thanks, started out as a rookie in Rails. :). Find some of the options for markup at [this link](http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/markup_processors.html). Markup, rDiscount and RedCloth are the most commonly used ones.