# Formating Ruby on Rails text fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a module @post where user can write their own posts. Problem is that these posts are without paragraphs and users can't start write in the new line. Maybe there is gems which allows that? I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.1.

For example this text:

**This text is bold**,

*This text is italic*

This is list:

1. item 1;
2. item 2;

But in my home page this will look like this:

This text is bold This text is italic This is list: 1. item 1; 2. item 2;

I hope you understand what I mean...

**@post show:**

```
<div id="content">
<div class="post">
    <h1 class="title"><%=@post.title%></h1>
    <p class="byline"style="text-align: right; font-weight: bold;">Raksts izveidots: <%= @post.created_at.utc.strftime("%d.%m.%Y") %></p>
    <div class="entry">
        <p><%= @post.content  %></p>
        <%= image_tag @post.bildes.url(:medium) %>
        <%= image_tag @post.bildes.url(:thumb) %>
    </div>
</div>
```

**@post form:**

```
<div id="content">
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>
  <ul>
  <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
  <% end %>
<% create_url = {:url=>{:action=>"create"}} if @post.new_record? %>
    <% form_for @post, :html => { :multipart => true } do |t| %>
      <b><%= t.label :title, 'Virsraksts:' %></b><br />
      <%= t.text_field :title %><br /><br />
      <b><%= t.label :content, 'Teksts:' %></b><br />
      <%= t.text_area :content %><br /><br />
      <b><%= t.label :bildes, 'Pievienot bildes:' %></b><br />
      <%= f.file_field :bildes %><br /><br />
      <%= t.submit %>
 <% end %>
      <%end%>
```

Comment: What do you mean they can't start writing in the new line? Please post the relevant code as well (probably just the view code is needed here).

Comment: I have edited my question, hope you will understand what I mean. :)

Comment: Still confused...the user input in a ``<input type='text' />``? and you want them to have styles? like ``bold`` ``italic``? am I correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe I didn't get you right. But I think you need to use a rich text editor on the page.

There's plenty of rich text editor out there, I recommend you to checkout [Tinymce](http://www.tinymce.com/), it's also used by wordpress.

So that the user could input in paragraphs and control other formats, which will result in html format and keep all the styles.

I am using `gem 'tinymce-rails'` to integrate Tinymce with rails. It just import the tinymce into the assets pipeline, not providing any helpers but I think it's quite good, works well with the assets pipeline, that's enough for me, I don't like some much wrapping for this, Here is the link: [tinymce-rails](https://github.com/spohlenz/tinymce-rails). You could also find a lot other gems which provide more close integration with rails.

Comment: Thank you! This gem is fantastic!!! For more information how to implement it: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/%22For_Dummies%22

Answer (score 4):

Rails's [`simple_format`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format) will get you paragraphs and line breaks formatted correctly when outputted as HTML, but for more advanced formatting you'll need something else.

[Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) is great if you can require that your users know the syntax (Markdown is what StackOverflow uses). There are several [Markdown formatters for Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/a/373446/211563).