# How may I use the StackExchange QA editor in my own website template?

Tags: javascript, html, css, text-editor

I've been using elrte js library to edit users personal profiles in a web site I made for artists database, but I kind don't like it because users complain about it's complexity and stability.

I like very much of this question/answer editor from StackOverflow and I's like to know if I can borrow the code for using in this website or it's copyrighted. If it's ok, where can I download the proper source-code?

Comment: See this for more information : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if these links would help you, I think what you want is MarkDown

- http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/
- http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/
- http://www.toptensoftware.com/markdowndeep/

You can find it in several languages: PHP, Perl, C#

Hope this helps

Comment: I downloaded the code from the last link. It has a DLL file. Do you know if this solution works on linux servers?

Comment: I am not sure. But you can contact the author: http://www.toptensoftware.com/markdowndeep/support

Comment: Depends on your application stack, which language you are using. There are also `ruby`, `python` implementation of `MarkDown`, they both work on *nix platform. For ruby, there is `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373002/better-ruby-markdown-interpreter`