# Markdown gem for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, markdown

What is one of the best gems out there to implement markdown in user posts?

I am currently looking to allow users to edit their text via profiles, discussions, etc. and the simple_format solution is no longer suitable for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[RedCarpet](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet) is the Ruby community's usual go-to choice for implementing Markdown, though there are other options ([Kramdown](https://github.com/gettalong/kramdown), for example).

To render your users' posts as Markdown with RedCarpet, you would write:

```
markdown = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(Redcarpet::Render::HTML, autolink: true)
markdown.render(@post.content)
```

With Kramdown, the API is a bit simpler:

```
Kramdown::Document.new(@post.content).to_html
```

RedCloth does support a wealth of configuration options, though, which Kramdown does not.

Answer (score 0):

[redcarpet](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet) + [markitup](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/) = [example](https://github.com/kanfet/markdown_example)

Comment: It seems like redcarpet would do the job alone? Not sure why markitup would be needed? I came across this SO thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373002/better-ruby-markdown-interpreter) but just not sure what may be outdated or worth it. Redcarpet is mentioned there too.

Comment: @JoeDayvie Yes Redcarpet can work alone.  Markitup for the convenience of users. Redcarpet - Last Version 3.3.2 - June 22, 2015 and  6,002,908 downloads :)